# Reset invalid value in lightning-input date to a blank value on click of a button

Tags: lightning-web-components, date, lightninginput

I have a lightning-input of type date. When I enter an invalid value in this field, there is a validation displayed 'Your entry does not match the allowed format MMM d, yyyy.' I want to clear this message along with the value in the input field on click of the clear button. I have tried using below approach, but it doesnt clear the value:

js:

```
clearAll(){
 this.template.querySelectorAll('.DateFilters').forEach(element => {
        element.value = '';
        element.setCustomValidity('');
        element.reportValidity();
    });
 }
```

html:

```
<lightning-input class="DateFilters slds-size_1-of-5 slds-m-left_x-small slds-m-top_x-small" 
type="date" label="Created Date" data-id="CreatedDate" data-item="from"></lightning-input> 

<lightning-button-group class="slds-float_left">
        <button class="wu btn btn-yellow slds-m-left_xx-small" onclick={clearAll}>Clear</button>
    </lightning-button-group>
```

Comment: Hi Krish, your code works fine in the LWC playground (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/8IFv147Ej/1/edit). Try comparing this carefully with your actual code and see if there might not be something else amiss.  Also -- you shouldn't need to use `setCustomValidity('')` if you never set it to a nonblank value in the first place.

Comment: @MatthewSouther This same code works in one of my dev sandboxes but fails in other sandboxes. What could be the reason?

Comment: Interesting.  Have you noted whether the sandboxes that are failing are on Summer '20 preview instances?  That's the only reason I can think of that something would break in one environment and not another.